# How to Disable Design Time Execution of a Custom Dependency Property?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dependency-properties

Implementing a custom Dependency Property on a Framework Element object causes my Visual Studio WPF designer to crash.  The designer appears to be executing my Dependency Property code upon load of the designer.  Consequently, the designer finds an unhandled exception (that I have thrown in the Dependency Property code myself) and breaks.

Is there any way to disable Design-Time execution of my custom Dependency Property so my designer still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check the [IsInDesignMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode.aspx) of the DependencyObject and choose to not throw the exception.